# Swagger/openApi configuration for nullable value inside list or Array

Tags: c#, swagger, openapi

I would like the swagger.json to hold the information about nullable type inside a list or array, any idea how to achieve that?

For example if I have the following model:

```
public class AccountSettingsDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal? Value { get; set; }
    public List<decimal?> ListValue { get; set; }
    public decimal?[] ArrayValue { get; set; }
}
```

The following swagger Setup

```
    services.AddSwaggerGen(config =>
    {
        config.MapType<decimal>(() => new OpenApiSchema { Type = "number", Format = "decimal" });
        config.UseAllOfToExtendReferenceSchemas();
    });
```

I get the following Json

```
"AccountSettingsDto": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int32"
          },
          "value": {
            "type": "number",
            "format": "decimal",
            "nullable": true
          },
          "listValue": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "type": "number",
              "format": "decimal"
            },
            "nullable": true
          },
          "arrayValue": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "type": "number",
              "format": "decimal"
            },
            "nullable": true
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
```

As you can see the "Value" property is correctly set as nullable but not the values inside a list or array.
As a wild guess I tried to add the following line in my swagger setup but it's obviously not working.

```
config.MapType<decimal?>(() => new OpenApiSchema { Type = "number", Format = "decimal?" });
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I did not looked properly at the signature of the setup. To solve my issue I only need to setup swagger as follow:

```
config.MapType<decimal>(() => new OpenApiSchema { Type = "number", Format = "decimal", Nullable = true });
```